# How to identify from which view controller we came from in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Hi I have a common view C which can be presented from both A and B. I want to change the navigation bar color in View C with respect to the view from which it was presented. Suppose C was presented from View then i want to make the navigation bar green in color and if C was presented from View B then i want to make the navigation bar of View C red in color. I am not able to figure out how it can be done.

Can someone give me a solution for the problem that i am facing.....

Thanks in advance

Comment: get viewController stack from navigation controller and check its A or B

Comment: Set a property on C inn`prepareForSegue` or however you push C

Comment: There are so many bad things in the question... A controller should not care about the color of the navigation controller, that should be set externally.

Answer (score 4):

You should do this by adding a property to your pushed view controller, and setting it in `prepare(for segue:)`

The advantage of doing it this way is that `ViewControllerC` doesn't have to assume any knowledge of which view controller presented it. This means that you can change the way it's presented (maybe modally rather than pushed onto the nav stack, or pushed by `ViewControllerZ`, say), without changing any of its code.

In `ViewControllerC`:

```
var navBarColor: UIColor?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super viewWillAppear(animated)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = navBarColor
}
```

Then in `ViewControllerA`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vcc = segue.destination as? ViewControllerC {
        vcc.navBarColor = .green
    }
}
```

…and in `ViewControllerB`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vcc = segue.destination as? ViewControllerC {
        vcc.navBarColor = .red
    }
}
```

**Extra credit**

If `.green` and `.red` are used to represent different "states", you might find it more useful for your property to represent that state. As an example…

```
enum StoreState {
    case buying, selling, browsing

    var navBarColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case buying: return .green
        case selling: return .red
        case browsing: return .blue
    }
}

var storeState: StoreState?

navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = storeState?.navBarColor
```

Answer (score 2):

On your C view controller,
get all the view controllers in the navigation stack.

```
let controllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers
```

Find and check the second last object in this array for type of A or B.

```
if controllers.count > 1, let expectedController = controllers[controllers.count-2] as? A {
// Your last controller was A type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by following code

```
 if let controllerA = self.navigationController?.presentingViewController as? ControllerA {
   print("arrived from controllerA")
} else if let controllerB = self.navigationController?.presentingViewController as? ControllerB {
   print("arrived from controllerB")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i would recommend is you can have an enum for this for example

```
enum transitionType {
    case first
    case second
}
```

then just create a variable in the viewcontroller "C" for this enum for example

```
var pushedFrom = transitionType.first
```

then all you have to do is when you create an object of viewcontroller C before pushing or presenting it, just provide its "pushedFrom" variable with the correct value, for example if its from viewcontroller A,

```
secondViewController.pushedFrom = .first
```

and if its viewcontroller B,

```
secondViewController.pushedFrom = .second
```

Then in the viewDidLoad of Viewcontroller "C", you can check what case the pushedfrom variable holds and change the navigationcontroller color accordingly.